# How To Detect When App Is Force Closed in Background Swift

Tags: ios, swift, forceclose

If my app is running in the background, and I force close it, how can I get the app to detect it was force closed in the background? Is there a specific function I can call to detect this?

Comment: The tricky part here is that apps are rarely in the background. (That term means they are not front-most but ARE receiving CPU time.) Usually you get a couple of seconds of background time and then you get suspended. (Still in memory but not getting any CPU time at all.) As others have pointed out, you can be terminated at any time without warning when you're suspended.

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
 func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

 }
```

within AppDelegate class to observe when the app will be terminated. [Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate)

Edit: Please, note that as it written in docs

> Suspended apps are not notified of termination

Comment: This is not called if the app is suspended in the background.

Comment: There is no way you can respond to this :(  According to docs: "Suspended apps are not notified of termination"

Comment: suspended apps are closed to clear up memory, therefore they probably don't want you using extra memory, makes sense